# object HTMLInputElement display on Firefox

Tags: javascript, object

javascript:

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","submit");
input.setAttribute("name","toopen:2:1");
input.setAttribute("value","Click here");
input.style.fontSize="20px";
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].appendChild(input);
```

how to fix this?

Comment: everything seems ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n2F9L/ in Chrome

Comment: it display me [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fKrUx/ IE9

Comment: What browser/OS does it not work for you?

Comment: Do you actually see `[object HTMLInputElement]` in those linked Fiddles, or only in your own code?

Comment: I'm using Firefox as mentioned